# jquery code shows permission denied with IE Edge & Iframes

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, iframe, microsoft-edge

Most of jquery code breaks with IE Edge & Iframes

Shows permission denied while accessing elements

Needed to shift to legacy javascript codebase with getElementById & getElementsByTagName. This works fine but it's impossible to change the whole code base for the application, it's a huge one.

Any suggestions or Does someone know any plugin to match things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me share what I found as an alternative/ or may be a solution to the problem.

```
$.extend($.expr[':'],{
    inline: function(a) {
        return $(a).css('display') === 'inline';
    }
});
```

With small pieces like the above code we can extend the capabilities or may be fix some of its errors.

References : [$.extend](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/)